# How to read sprite position properly on the loop; im able see edges of the other images :\

Tags: android, sprite, sprite-sheet

I've searched and tried few ways to do this, but can't get it right. Following code produces an ugly result; created Bitmaps contains edges from multiple icons, like 10% top and 10% left from other icons and 80% from the target icon. but first Bitmap (the one that is created on x=0, y=0) is perfect but rest are not.

Please let me know what im doing wrong here. Cheers!

```
private Bitmap[][]  createIcons(Bitmap sprite_sheet, int rows, int cols)
{
    Bitmap[][] iconBox_TMP = new Bitmap[20][20];
    int width   = sprite_sheet.getWidth()   / cols;
    int height  = sprite_sheet.getHeight()  / rows;

    try{


        for (int i=0; i<rows; i += 1) 
        {

            for (int j=0; j<cols; j += 1) 
            {

                /*
                            //same result with matrix
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
                    iconBox_TMP[i][j] = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            sprite_sheet, 
                            j*width, 
                            i*height, 
                            width, 
                            height, 
                            matrix, 
                            true);
                    matrix.reset();
                    matrix = null;
                    */

                    iconBox_TMP[i][j] = Bitmap.createBitmap(sprite_sheet,
                    width * j, 
                    height * i, 
                    width, 
                    height);

                    Log.d("createIcons()", "(" + i + "," + j + ") X: " + j*width + ", Y: " + (i*height) + ", W: " + width + ", H: " + height);

            }

        }   


    }catch(Exception e){}

    return iconBox_TMP;
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the LogCat output:

```
02-10 04:41:01.281: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,0) X: 0, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.281: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,1) X: 79, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.281: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,2) X: 158, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.281: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,3) X: 237, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.281: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,4) X: 316, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.285: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,5) X: 395, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.285: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,6) X: 474, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.285: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,7) X: 553, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.285: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,8) X: 632, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.285: D/createIcons()(4961): (0,9) X: 711, Y: 0, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.285: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,0) X: 0, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.285: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,1) X: 79, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.289: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,2) X: 158, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.289: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,3) X: 237, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.289: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,4) X: 316, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.289: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,5) X: 395, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.289: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,6) X: 474, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.289: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,7) X: 553, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.289: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,8) X: 632, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.289: D/createIcons()(4961): (1,9) X: 711, Y: 79, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.292: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,0) X: 0, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.292: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,1) X: 79, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.292: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,2) X: 158, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.292: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,3) X: 237, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.292: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,4) X: 316, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.292: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,5) X: 395, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.292: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,6) X: 474, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.292: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,7) X: 553, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.292: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,8) X: 632, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.296: D/createIcons()(4961): (2,9) X: 711, Y: 158, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.296: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,0) X: 0, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.296: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,1) X: 79, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.296: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,2) X: 158, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.296: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,3) X: 237, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.296: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,4) X: 316, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.296: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,5) X: 395, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.296: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,6) X: 474, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.300: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,7) X: 553, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.324: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,8) X: 632, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.324: D/createIcons()(4961): (3,9) X: 711, Y: 237, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.324: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,0) X: 0, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.324: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,1) X: 79, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.328: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,2) X: 158, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.328: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,3) X: 237, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.328: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,4) X: 316, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.328: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,5) X: 395, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.328: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,6) X: 474, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.328: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,7) X: 553, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.328: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,8) X: 632, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.328: D/createIcons()(4961): (4,9) X: 711, Y: 316, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.332: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,0) X: 0, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.332: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,1) X: 79, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.332: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,2) X: 158, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.332: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,3) X: 237, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.332: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,4) X: 316, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.332: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,5) X: 395, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.332: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,6) X: 474, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.332: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,7) X: 553, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.335: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,8) X: 632, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.335: D/createIcons()(4961): (5,9) X: 711, Y: 395, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.335: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,0) X: 0, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.335: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,1) X: 79, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.335: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,2) X: 158, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.335: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,3) X: 237, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.335: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,4) X: 316, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.335: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,5) X: 395, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.339: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,6) X: 474, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.339: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,7) X: 553, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.339: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,8) X: 632, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.339: D/createIcons()(4961): (6,9) X: 711, Y: 474, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.339: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,0) X: 0, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.339: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,1) X: 79, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.339: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,2) X: 158, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.339: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,3) X: 237, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.343: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,4) X: 316, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.343: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,5) X: 395, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.343: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,6) X: 474, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.343: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,7) X: 553, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.343: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,8) X: 632, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
02-10 04:41:01.343: D/createIcons()(4961): (7,9) X: 711, Y: 553, W: 79, H: 79
```

Comment: Can you show us your sprite_sheet ? (10% overlapping seems huge)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Orabig, There's no image upload option here :(, but let me describe.. it's a set of small icons with the width of 53 x 53 (width and height), around 200 icons per sheet, placed one after another without any transparent space. It is to draw them on ListView component after loading them separately into a Bitmap multi dimentional array. It works when loading them one by one, but as sprite sheet, it has the overlapping issue. I wonder if there's anything wrong with the createIcons() code, according to that it should follow the width / height precisely till end.

Comment: Well, you could upload you sheet on another site (imageshack or so). Also, We'll need the line calling createIcons(), the parameters value, and the log output...

Comment: Hi Orabig:
The first icon in the ListView drawing at bitmap[0][0] (row, col) position, the last item draws the bitmap at; bitmap[3][9] (row, col) positions, it get worse at the end. 

The result: http://postimage.org/image/yzakuf66p/
The sprite sheet: http://postimage.org/image/4j4nwaknl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a rounding error, because on your original sprite sheet, each cell should be 53x53.
But, when you load the bitmap, it makes it a bigger bitmap to fit the resolution of the device  (hdpi)

By converting from mdpi to hdpi, your bitmap grows 50%, and the cells should be 79.5 pixels wide. But of course, this number is rounded down to 79 pixel, thus the offset error for some sprites.

If your sprite sheet is a resource, then you should provide a hdpi version, which will be 735x636 pixels. That way, you'll be able to control the conversion yourself (and you'll discover that 735 is not a multiple of 10, so maybe you'll want to change these dimensions slightly).

Comment: I see what you mean... Sure it resizes the image, but I thought it gets the precise position without rounding it because im not calling Math.round or anything, thus couldn't locate the issue. Thanks a lot for clearing this. It helps me a lot =)